# To use ddply funciton into a function into another package

Tags: r, package

I wrote a R package following Hadley Wickham R packages book and using devtools functions to do it (using R 3.2.3 and RStudio 0.99.489 on a Mac). In one of my function I use the `plyr::ddply` function to summarize data:

```
plyr::ddply(dat, c("Subject", "Answer"), summarize, Freq = length(Answer), .drop = F)
```

When checking the package with `devtools::check()` a note appears in the status specifing that there is no visible binding for global variable ‘summarize’. If I do not remove this note and build my package, my function return an error because summarize cannot be found. If I specify in the begining of my function that `summarize = NULL`, the note disapear. But after re-building the package, my function return an error because the `summarize` argument in `ddply` is not effective and nothing is summarized. So I have the choise between an error... or another error.

So is there a way out of this situation? Or is it not possible to use `plyr` functions into another package function?

Thanks by advance if someone have a solution!

Comment: `summarize` is a function of `plyr`, not a variable. You probably need to import this function.

Comment: What would happen if you have `plyr::ddply(dat, c("Subject", "Answer"), plyr::summarize, Freq = length(Answer), .drop = F)`?

Comment: @Pascal. Indeed summarize is a function of the `plyr` package but it seems to me that if I Import `plyr` in the DESCRIPTION file of my package (what I did), `summarize` should be loaded.

Comment: If you import `plyr`, why do you use the syntax `plyr::ddply`?

Comment: @Kota. I try this, but it does not change anything. Maybe the problem is that `summarize` is called inside another function, because if I use `plyr::arrange` or `plyr::ldply` it works well.

Comment: @Pascal. I followed instruction of the R packages book from Hadley Wickham, where he begins to recommand using `pkg::foo` syntaxe to use non base functions. However, there is maybe no need to use this syntaxe + Import. I should maybe go back to the book to make sure about that. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Hmm.  I succeeded in package build with using `plyr::summarize` inside the function and worked well.  Weird...  By the way, just adding `plyr` in the Imports section of DESCRIPTION does not load the package.  You can attach the package by writing `#' @import plyr` somewhere in your script (this is not recommended by Wickham though).